# Liquibase XmlElement error exception when running within gradle and Java13

Tags: java, gradle, liquibase

### **Problem**

I recently started using liquibase with Spring Boot (2.2.1). Build tool is **gradle** and **JDK** version is **13**. I've integrated **liquibase plugin** according to readme page on github.

I faced strange behaviour when I was starting liquibase tasks such as update (gradle update).  I received an **Java NoClassDefFoundException for XmlElement attribute** (sorry because I lost exact Exception stacktrace and message), but I solved this issue and would like to share my solution here.

Comment: I'd suggest you split your post into question an an answer. Then it will be easier to find the answer for those who face this problem.

Comment: There is still no answer. In the question post keep only the question. Then click on the "Answer" button and write the answer. Then mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

It is well known issue when you move from Java 8 to Java 9 and upper and it solves by adding dependency to javax.xml.bind. However when you deal with liquibase gradle plugin adding compile 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api' or runtime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api' to dependency section doesn not helps. I solved this by adding liquibaseRuntime 'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api', this is a part of my gradle script:

```
dependencies {
   // my project dependencies
   // ...

   // liquibase plugin deps
   liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.1'
    liquibaseRuntime "jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.2"
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.1.RELEASE'
    //liquibaseRuntime 'org.liquibase:liquibase-groovy-dsl:2.0.1'
    liquibaseRuntime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4.1211.jre7'
    liquibaseRuntime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.2.3'
    liquibaseRuntime 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'
    liquibaseRuntime sourceSets.main.output 
}
```

I hope my solution could help your to save your time.